# Copying range of values from Google Sheet to other

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy the range of values from one spreadsheet to another (A1:H45). I tried the code below. In spite of copying the values of Cells A1:H45, its copying A1 Cell data in a new sheet throughout A1:H45, which means the same data getting copied 45 times.

```
function Copy()
{
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1IK6YsZS3_NNAlFA41d8uKriPzfZs_2Ukyh94eeBFj40'); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('CURRENT'); 
var range = ss.getRange('A1:H45'); 
var data = range.getValues();
var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("New sheet");
if (yourNewSheet != null) 
{

    activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(yourNewSheet);
}
yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
yourNewSheet.setName("Name of your new sheet");
yourNewSheet.getRange(yourNewSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,45,8).setValue(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
function Copy()
{
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1IK6YsZS3_NNAlFA41d8uKriPzfZs_2Ukyh94eeBFj40'); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('CURRENT'); 
var range = ss.getRange('A1:H45'); 
var data = range.getValues();
var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("New sheet");
if (yourNewSheet != null) 
{

    activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(yourNewSheet);
}
yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
yourNewSheet.setName("Name of your new sheet");
yourNewSheet.getRange(yourNewSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,45,8).setValues(data);
}
```

Your code is perfect. All you had to do was use `setValues` (plural) instead of `setValue` :)

Comment: Glad this helped! Kindly consider accepting the answer too :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer